# how would you check if a row already exists jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

so far i have the below which i want to instert a row only if that row doesn't already exist.

i'm using .find() is the correct usage? i have also tried contains()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#add').click(function() {

    var data = $('#skusearch').val();
    if (data.length) 
    {

        var data = $('#skusearch').val().split('-');
        var result =$('tr').find(data[0]);
        if (result === true)
        {
            console.log("row already exists")
        }
        else 
        {
            $('tbody').append("<tr id='"+data[0]+"'><td>"+data[0]+"</td><td>"+data[1]+"</td><td data-editable='true'>1</td><td><center><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></center></td></tr>");
            $('#table').editableTableWidget();
            $('#skusearch').val('');
        }

    };

});

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not searching after the ID, so change it to `"#" + data[0]` and also not checking for `true`, because find returns the searched object

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#add').click(function() {

    var data = $('#skusearch').val();
    if (data.length) 
    {

        var data = $('#skusearch').val().split('-');
        var result = $("#" + data[0]);
        if (result.length)
        {
            console.log("row already exists")
        }
        else 
        {
            $('tbody').append("<tr id='"+data[0]+"'><td>"+data[0]+"</td><td>"+data[1]+"</td><td data-editable='true'>1</td><td><center><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></center></td></tr>");
            $('#table').editableTableWidget();
            $('#skusearch').val('');
        }

    };

});

});
```

Comment: Trying to find an element within itself? :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
    var result =$('tr').find(data[0]);
    if (result === true)
```

With:

```
    var result = $('#' + data[0]).length;
    if( result )
```